# Connect nodes dynamically by a line when dragged dropped

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a requirement where I want to connect multiple nodes with a  tag dynamically when dragged dropped. Below is the use case

My drag drop area -

[image]

When I am dragging `Test5` on top of `Test1` it is now looking like this

[image]

But I want to create a line between them like below example

[image]

This one I just checked can be done by below code. But I don't know how to dynamically fit it into my drop event

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="display:block;" width="740" height="657" viewBox="-143,-88.5,740,657">
        <g node-id="2" style="opacity: 1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,135,180)" class="node" sl="1" l="1">
            <rect x="0" y="0" height="120" width="250" fill="#039BE5" stroke-width="1" stroke="#aeaeae" rx="5" ry="5"></rect>
            <text width="230" style="font-size: 18px;" fill="#ffffff" x="125" y="95" text-anchor="middle">Ashley Barnett</text>
        </g>
        <g node-id="4" style="opacity: 1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,360)" class="node" sl="2" l="2">
            <rect x="0" y="0" height="120" width="250" fill="#039BE5" stroke-width="1" stroke="#aeaeae" rx="5" ry="5"></rect>
            <text width="230" style="font-size: 18px;" fill="#ffffff" x="125" y="95" text-anchor="middle">Elliot Patel</text>
        </g>
        <g node-id="5" style="opacity: 1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,270,360)" class="node" sl="2" l="2">
            <rect x="0" y="0" height="120" width="250" fill="#039BE5" stroke-width="1" stroke="#aeaeae" rx="5" ry="5"></rect>
            <text width="230" style="font-size: 18px;" fill="#ffffff" x="125" y="95" text-anchor="middle">Lynn Hussain</text>
        </g>
        <g link-id="[2][5]" class="link ">
            <path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="#aeaeae" stroke-width="1px" fill="none" d="M260,300 260,322 Q260,330 268,330 L387,330 Q395,330 395,338 L395,360"></path>
        </g>
        <g link-id="[2][4]" class="link ">
            <path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="#aeaeae" stroke-width="1px" fill="none" d="M260,300 260,322 Q260,330 252,330 L133,330 Q125,330 125,338 L125,360"></path>
        </g>
        <g control-expcoll-id="2" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,245,285)" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="15" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#aeaeae" stroke-width="1"></circle>
            <line x1="4" y1="15" x2="26" y2="15" stroke-width="1" stroke="#aeaeae"></line>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

I know it can be achieveable by  tag but I have no idea, how to implement this.

Below is my drop event

```
drop: function (component, event, helper) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data)).className = "nodeclass slds-card";
}
```

HTML -

```html
<div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
  <div style="display: table-row; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 16%; display: table-cell; background: white;" ondrop="{!c.drop}" ondragover="{!c.allowDrop}">
      <aura:iteration var="objRecord" items="{!v.ContactData.records}" indexVar="index">
        <div class="slds-card" draggable="true" ondragstart="{!c.drag}" data-drag-id="{!index}" id="{!objRecord.Id}"> {!objRecord.Name} </div>
      </aura:iteration>
    </div>
    <div id="dropzone" style="border: 4px solid grey;height:28rem" draggable="true" ondragstart="{!c.drag}" ondrop="{!c.drop}" ondragover="{!c.allowDrop}"> Test </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any clue how to do it.

Comment: any help how to proceed..

Comment: Please update your question with a "working" [mcve] - ie. what you have so far.  If people have to do a lot of work just to stitch your bits together, then you are probably not going to receive any help.